# Flutter with Riverpod: Update just one property in my model

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, riverpod

I'm used to using GetX and doing my models with it. But with Riverpod I don't understand a concept.

I have a product list that is created with an async call (an endpoint) and I would like to be able to select several products to make an order.

Here is my example model:

```
class ProductModel{
  String name;
  bool isSelected;

  ProductModel({
    required this.name,
    required this.isSelected,
  });
}
```

And this is how i load my products:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) { 

    final productsAsync = ref.watch(productsProvider(orderId));

    return productsAsync.when( 
      data: (products) {  
        return Scaffold( 
          ....
```

And this is my Icon button where I can select : I don't know how to refresh the view easily

```
child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: product!.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      final currentProduct = product![index];

      return ExpansionTile(
        leading: InkWell(
          customBorder: const CircleBorder(),
          onTap: () { 
            //Tried with a productProvider created just after the data...
            // ref.read(productProvider.notifier).state![index].isSelected = !ref.read(productProvider.notifier).state![index].isSelected;
            // currentProduct.isSelected = !currentProduct.isSelected;
          },
          child: Icon( 
            //Tried with a productProvider...
            ref.watch(productProvider)![index].isSelected ? Icons.check_circle_rounded : Icons.circle_outlined,
            color: bColors.green,
          ),
        ),
```

With GetX I'll make sure to put my "isSelected" variable in my model as "Rx" but with Riverpod I don't see how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `AsyncNotifier` with the state of `List<ProductModel>`. In the `build` method, async call your endpoint and update the `state`.

Next, create an asynchronous method `onTapSelected` and change `state` there. In this case, you have to use `state = List.of(changedList);` The widget will rebuild automatically as soon as `state` changes.

You can also use `ref.watch(yourProvider.select)` to filter out conversions.

Your models must be immutable, have fields `final`. For easier interaction and immutability support, look into using freezed (before dart 3.0 arrives :))

References:

[Flutter Riverpod 2.0: The Ultimate Guide](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-state-management-riverpod/)